# Ampscript - Remove dash from XML numerical field (Marketing Cloud)

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am pulling in a numerical field from an XML table which could include 1 or up to 20 products. The "QuantityOrdered" field includes a dash (Ex: 6-)after every number I would like to remove. I have tried to remove using substring subtract function although the final render removes more than 1 character resulting in no data.

```
set @OrderDetails = BuildRowsetFromXml(@xmldata,"//OrderDetails/OrderDetail",1)
set @OrderDetailsRows = RowCount(@OrderDetails)

for @p = 1 TO @OrderDetailsRows do
 set @row = Row(@OrderDetails, @p)


 IF NOT EMPTY(Field(Row(@OrderDetails,@p),'QuantityOrdered_att'))
 THEN 
 SET @QuantityOrd = substring(@QuantityOrd,1,subtract(indexOf(@QuantityOrd," "),1))

ENDIF
```

Comment: If `@QuantityOrd` is expected to be whole numbers, removing the dashes via replacement (e.g., `set @QuantityOrd = replace(@QuantityOrd, "-", "")`) could be a simpler approach.

Answer (score 1):

@MarkG - Thanks Mark - That worked. I recalled the attribute and added to function Set @Quan1 = Field(Row(@OrderDetails,@p),'QuantityOrdered_att'))
     IF NOT EMPTY(Field(Row(@OrderDetails,@p),'QuantityOrdered_att'))
 THEN 
Set @QuantityOrd = replace(@Quan1, "-", ""))
Much appreciated!